# UIDocument's documentState never comes to UIDocumentStateProgressAvailable while calling openWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios11

I am trying to get download progress(NSProgress) value of UIDocument (iCloud document) while opening through openWithCompletionHandler method. As per iOS 11 SDK , UIDocument object will come to state of UIDocumentStateProgressAvailable, when progress value will be available. But it doesnt give value at all. Any idea ? Thanks

```
CustomDocument *doc = [[CustomDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:documentURL];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification object:doc queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
// get called only once when the document state is Normal
                if ([doc progress]) {
                    transitionController.loadingProgress = [doc progress]; // never get called as doc.progress is always nil
                }
            }];
            [doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success) {
                    // successfully opened without being in  UIDocumentStateProgressAvailable state
                }
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:doc];
            }];
```